# Want to Transpose time data across a group of ID variables in Python

Tags: python-3.x, transpose

I am 2 hours into python. Would appreciate all help I can get.

**This is what I HAVE:**

```css
District  yyyyww  metric 
ABC1      202001  100
ABC1      202002  121 
ABC1      202003  112
ABC2      202001  90
ABC2      202002  71 
ABC2      202003  12
```

**This is what I NEED:**

```css
    District  y202001  y202002  y202003
    ABC1      100       121     112
    ABC2       90        71      12
```

The reason I want to do this is so that I can re-transpose the dataset across District and get 0's for those timepoints where I have missing data.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want your code to do what you want, then you need to show it to us, so we can help you.

Comment: I don't know where to begin, I really don't.